# Fundamental differences between utilizing CoffeeScript `extends` vs. Backbone.js `extend`

Tags: inheritance, backbone.js, coffeescript

What are the fundamental differences between utilizing CoffeeScript `extends` vs. Backbone.js `extend`?

For example, how is

```
class User extends Backbone.Model
```

different from

```
User = Backbone.Model.extend()
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The two are intended to be equivalent. To quote the Backbone.js changelog:

> 0.3.0: Backbone classes may now be seamlessly inherited by CoffeeScript classes.

Both CoffeeScript's `Child extends Parent` and Backbone's `Child = Parent.extend()` do three important things:

1. **(Most important)** They set `Child.prototype` to `new ctor`, where `ctor` is a function whose prototype is `Parent.prototype`. That establishes prototypal inheritance.
2. They copy all of `Parent`'s static properties onto `Child`.
3. They set `Child.__super__ = Parent`. This is mainly to support CoffeeScript's Ruby-like `super` keyword in `Child`'s methods.

Answer (score 2):

There are some differences. If you use Backbone's `extend()` method, you lose out on CoffeeScript's class syntactical sugar like `super` and static properties/methods.

```
Model = Backbone.Model.extend
  set: (attrs, options) ->
    super
```

which compiles to (incorrect)...

```
var Model;
Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  set: function(attrs, options) {
    return set.__super__.constructor.call(this, arguments);
  }
});
```

You can use super this way though:

```
Model = Bakbone.Model.extend()
Model::set = ->
  super
```

which compiles to (correct)...

```
var Model;
Model = Backbone.Model.extend();

Model.prototype.set = function() {
  return Model.__super__.set.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

The drawback to coffeescript classes, depending on how you organize and compile your code, each class could have CoffeeScript's `__extends()` function appended to the top of the class definition in the compiled javascript. This extra bit of code duplicated dozens of times can considerably balloon your files. Especially true if using a framework that wraps your code in common.js modules.

So I would use Backbone's `extend()` by default for lean compiled code. Then when you have a special case that would be nice to use coffeescript class syntax, then go ahead and use it... *sparingly*.

Comment: CoffeeScript optimizes code when it compiles it, although the resulting file may be slightly more characters wouldn't using CoffeeScript `class` generally execute more efficiently?