# Coffeescript class extend more bloat than Backbone extend

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am just beginning to learn Coffeescript and cannot find a definite answer to why I should use

```
class Model extends Backbone.Model
    urlRoot: '//some/url'
```

compiles to

```
Model = (function(_super) {
    __extends(Model, _super);

    function Model() {
        _ref = Model.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
        return _ref;
    }

    Model.prototype.urlRoot = '//some/url';

    return Model;

})(Backbone.Model);
```

as opposed to

```
Model = Backbone.Model.extend
    urlRoot: '//some/url'
```

compiles to

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '//some/url'
});
```

The main reason I am asking is because the former is used in nearly all examples I have looked at. However, it creates 'much' more bloat when compiled as opposed to the latter. I did read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243679/fundamental-differences-between-utilizing-coffeescript-extends-vs-backbone-js), but the answers seem to differ.

Comment: What exactly do you think "bloat" is? Why do you think it's bad? If you're talking about verbosity of code then... Why? It's generated code, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @meagar, well if you writing a large scale app with many models, collections and views, the generated code definitely needs to matter. Also I would like the generated code to be easily read by those who have not yet learnt Coffeescript.

Comment: @TyroneMichael No, it really doesn't, any more than the generated binary matters in a modern desktop application.

Comment: Looking at the results of these, the difference is about 17 bytes per class once run through a minifier. In a (fairly large) app I have about 45 classes, which equates to 765 bytes. Compare this to the total of 140,000 bytes it currently is. Worrying about this is a micro-optimization at best.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since you're asking just about the bloat, let's have a look at some code.

### JavaScript with `Backbone.Model.extend`

If you open up the Backbone source code, you'll see the `extend` function is the following:

```
var extend = function(protoProps, staticProps) {
    var parent = this;
    var child;

    if (protoProps && _.has(protoProps, 'constructor')) { // _.has comes from
      child = protoProps.constructor;                     // underscore, even 
    } else {                                              // more 'bloat'
      child = function(){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); };
    }

    _.extend(child, parent, staticProps);                // more underscore

    var Surrogate = function(){ this.constructor = child; };
    Surrogate.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = new Surrogate;

    if (protoProps) _.extend(child.prototype, protoProps);

    child.__super__ = parent.prototype;

    return child;
  };
```

### What actually happens here:

When we call

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({urlRoot: '//some/url' });
```

we get something like:

```
  // Create new constructor which calls the parent constructor
  var Model;
  if (({}).hasOwnProperty.call({urlRoot: '//some/url' }, 'constructor') {
      // this is false so...                    
  } else {
      Model = function(){ return Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments); };
  }

  // Set up prototype chain
  var Surrogate = function(){ this.constructor = model; };
  Surrogate.prototype = Backbone.Model.prototype;
  Model.prototype = new Surrogate;

  // Add properties to the child prototype
  // Same as:
  // Model.prototype.urlRoot = '//some/url';
  _.extend(Model.prototype, { urlRoot: '//some/url' });

  // Set the magical __super__ property
  Model.__super__ = Backbone.Model.prototype;
```

### CoffeeScript with `extends`

Compare that with the CoffeeScript code. You will see that when you use `extends` a magical function called `__extends` gets added to the start of your file, which (when formatted) looks like:

```
__extends = function(child, parent) { 
    for (var key in parent) { 
        if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) 
            child[key] = parent[key]; 
    }

    function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } 
    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; 
    child.prototype = new ctor(); 

    child.__super__ = parent.prototype; 

    return child; 
};
```

which is combined with the generated JS:

```
var Model = (function(_super) {
    __extends(Model, _super);

    function Model() {
        _ref = Model.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
        return _ref;
    }

    Model.prototype.urlRoot = '//some/url';

    return Model;

})(Backbone.Model);
```

### What actually happens here:

When we call

```
Model extends Backbone.Model
    urlRoot: '//some/url'
```

we get something like:

```
// Create new constructor which calls the parent constructor
var Model = function () {
    return Model.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}

// Copy static properties from Backbone.Model to Model
for (var key in Backbone.Model) {
    if (__hasProp.call(Backbone.Model, key)) 
        Model[key] = Backbone.Model[key]; 
}

// Set up prototype chain
function ctor() { this.constructor = Model; } 
ctor.prototype = Backbone.Model.prototype; 
Model.prototype = new ctor(); 

// Add properties to the child prototype
Model.prototype.urlRoot = '//some/url';

// Set the magical __super__ property
Model.__super__ = Backbone.Model.prototype;
```

### What do we see?

They look pretty similar don't they?

CoffeeScript is just JavaScript. If you are already using Backbone and want to avoid adding in the `__extends` function in your generated source, then use `Backbone.Model.extend`. If you want to avoid adding in Backbone all together then `extends` does practically the same thing. The reason that so many examples don't use the latter is that Backbone is not required to use CoffeeScript - it just wouldn't make sense to have an example which relies on an external library.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the awesome informative answer. I have been developing in Backbone since it's early release. I just looked at some examples where Backbone and Coffeescript were used in conjunction, and most use the class example. If you have many models, collections, and views, the file size can quickly add up.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/backbone-extend-vs-coffeescript-class-extends compares the run times of the two extends - they are similar.

Comment: The key distinction here is that Backbone extends is a method call and Coffeescript extend emits code. This has a very different impact for code size. You need to be aware of what you are optimizing for.

Comment: I'm not sure if this adds value to the answer, but the author of both Backbone and CoffeeScript is the same greatest Jeremy Ashkenas https://github.com/jashkenas/ , so I doubt there will be a big ( if any ) difference in how the two extends work.