# Is there a way to extend prototypes in a more coffee script like manner?

Tags: coffeescript, prototype, underscore.js, marionette

Typically, when using Coffee Script I add methods to Backbone.Marionette.Application like so...

```
do (Backbone) ->
  _.extend Backbone.Marionette.Application::,
    testMethod: ->
      console.log "I was here"
```

I was wondering if there is a more "Coffee Script'ish" way to do this.  IE with the extends keyword and not using underscores extend.

Comment: Why don't you subclass `Backbone.Marionette.Application` instead? Monkey patching is neat and all but it shouldn't be the first tool you reach for.

Comment: Earlier discussion on using Coffeescript `extends` versus Backbone `extend`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243679

Comment: whats the advantage over Backbone.Marionette.Application::testMethod = -> console.log "I was here?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you have it written, there is no object to extend your app with, but if you want to create an object 'subclassed' you could do something like

```
class MyApp extends Backbone.Marionette.Application
  testMethod: -> console.log "I was here"
```

which is basically what @mu is suggesting in his comment.